# Detect deleted file with bookmark in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsnotifications

I am tracking the location of a file with a bookmark which I store in NSUserDefaults, so that if a user decides to move it, my app can still access it. I create the initial bookmark with

```
- (NSData *)bookmarkFromURL:(NSURL *)url {
NSData *bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationMinimalBookmark
                 includingResourceValuesForKeys:NULL
                                  relativeToURL:NULL
                                          error:NULL];
return bookmark;
}
```

each time I need the file I retrieve the bookmark from NSUserDefaults and I resolve the NSURL with

```
- (NSURL *)urlFromBookmark:(NSData *)bookmark {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmark
                                       options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI
                                 relativeToURL:NULL
                           bookmarkDataIsStale:NULL
                                         error:NULL];
return url;
}
```

It works like a charm. The only additional feature that I would like is to be able to detect if the user deletes the file. Of course, I can check periodically if the NSURL returns nil, but I would like to be notified straight away. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use NSNotification to detect when a bookmark has been deleted and then I guess save to NSUserDefaults.

Something like this in the class which can delete bookmarks;

```
    -(void)deleteBookmark:(NSData*)bkmark{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"XXBookmarkDeletedNotification" object:nil];
    }
```

And then set up another class to listen for the notification and respond to it.

```
  // Setup the notification when the object is initialised or view is loaded.
     -(void)setupNotifications{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleBookmarkDeletedNotification:) name:@"XXBookmarkDeletedNotification" object:nil];
     } 

 -(void)handleBookmarkDeletedNotification:(NSNotification*)notification{
// do whatever you need to do here, for example set a "deleted" flag in NSUserDefaults
 }

 // You to need to remove your class from the list of observers when you are done.
 -(void)removeNotifications{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"XXBookmarkDeletedNotification" object:nil];
  }
```